# Submit button doesn't work on click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When I click on the submit button, form isn't submitted. There's a field for to submit a rating as well(:point). You click on a star and that should be a value for hidden_field.

```
<%= form_for [@post, @comment], remote: true, method: :post, 'data-update-target' => 'comments', class: 'comments' do  |f| %>

...

    <%= f.hidden_field :point %>
  <div class="rating-comments"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.rating-comments').raty({
          click: function(score, evt) {
            $("#point").val(score);
            return console.log(score);
          }
        });
    </script>

...

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit " Submit ", :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>

<% end %>
...
```

comments.coffee file

```
ready = ->
  $("form[data-update-target]").bind "ajax:success", (evt, data) ->
    target = $(this).data("update-target")
    $("#" + target).prepend data
    $('#content').val('')

  score = $('.rating-total').data('score')
  $('.rating-total').raty({
    haftShow: true,
    score: score,
    readOnly: true
  })

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

LOG

```
Started POST "/posts/1/comments" for 92.241.136.221 at 2014-04-11 16:25:46 +0000                                                                                                  
Processing by CommentsController#create as JS                                                                                                                                      
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "comment"=>{"point"=>"-1", "title"=>"", "content"=>""}, "score"=>"4", "commit"=>" Submit ", "post_id"=>"1"}                                           
  Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "[posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]                                                                                      
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]                                                                                        
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction                                                                                                                                                         
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction                                                                                                                                                      
  Rendered shared/_categories.html.erb (0.9ms)                                                                                                                                        
  Rendered comments/_form.html.erb (5.5ms)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "relationships" ON "users"."id" = "relationships"."followed_id" WHERE "relationships"."follower_id" = ?  [["follower_id", 1]]     
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "relationships" ON "users"."id" = "relationships"."follower_id" WHERE "relationships"."followed_id" = ?  [["followed_id", 1]]     
  Rendered shared/_stats.html.erb (123.0ms)                                                                                                                                           
  Rendered shared/_user_mainprofile.html.erb (125.2ms)                                                                                                                                
  Rendered comments/new.html.erb within layouts/application (135.6ms)                                                                                                             
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.6ms)                                                                                                                                           
Completed 200 OK in 230ms (Views: 214.9ms | ActiveRecord: 1.1ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: That's unfortunate...sadly we don't have nearly enough information to help you diagnose the problem. We need to see the entire form (including where the submit button is), any error messages, relevant log messages, etc. The problem could be any number of reasons.

Comment: If the form is not submited, it's usually a javascript error. Also `<% f.hidden_field :point %>` should be `<%= f.hidden_field :point %>`

Comment: I updated the post. What do you think?

Comment: Is your browser reporting any JS errors on submission? Also, you said *There's a field for to submit a rating as well*; I'm not quite sure I understand, but do you have a form within a form, or do you mean an actual Rails `fields_for`?

Comment: No, it's a simple field. You just have to select a star(score). I updated the post with a log.

Comment: Hmm, ok so it looks like the form is indeed submitting. What made you believe it was not submitting?

Comment: When I click on it, I don't get redirected where I should be or see Comment with id=1. It started happening when I added this at the beginning - remote: true, method: :post, 'data-update-target' => 'comments', class: 'comments' -

Comment: @Xantar Oh ok, you mean the page doesn't change? That's because you set the `remote: true` parameter on the `form_for`. Its submitting through ajax asynchronously, and won't change pages like a normal form submit. That's why you had to bind to `"ajax:success"` in order to do something after the form finished. Does that make sense?

Comment: Also, I just noticed a mistaken, it looks like you're calling your `ready` function twice, once for `$(document).ready(ready)` and again right after for `$(document).on('page:load', ready)`. Its possible you'll end up with odd duplicate behaviour / events and such, if you haven't see it already.

Comment: Now, I get an error "Point must be greater than or equal to 0". See here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23001781/1-error-prohibited-this-comment-from-being-saved-point-must-be-greater-than-o)

Comment: @Xantar Ok, so your validation is failing. If you look at the log, you see it is indeed less than zero (`"comment"=>{"point"=>"-1"...`). You're in a better position to determine why though, as that is the domain of your application at this point.